# Script appium in ruby get error rescue in appium_server_version

Tags: ruby, appium

When I try run my script appium (in ruby) after connection with device my script broken with this error:

[image: error]

**information:**
Appium 1.20.2
Ruby 2.6.3

my script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'appium_lib'

username = 'user'
access_key = '123'

desired_caps = {
    caps: {
        platformName: "Android",
        apiKey: "**********",
        deviceId: "***************",
        appPackage: "banco.devicelab.com.br.banco",
        appActivity: ".MainActivity",
        newCommandTimeout: "3600"
    },
    appium_lib: {
        server_url: 'http://EXTERNAL_URL/wd/hub',
        wait: 60,
        debug: false,
        export_session: true
    }
}

appium_driver = Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps, true)
driver = appium_driver.start_driver

driver.find_element(:id, "banco.devicelab.com.br.banco:id/main_button_login").click
driver.find_element(:id, "banco.devicelab.com.br.banco:id/login_email").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(:id, "banco.devicelab.com.br.banco:id/login_password").send_keys(access_key)
driver.find_element(:id, "banco.devicelab.com.br.banco:id/login_button").click
sleep 5


driver.driver_quit
```

Comment: have you checked that /api/mobile/wd/hub/status is available and doesn't return 404?

Comment: this error appear after appium execute -> http://0.0.0.0:8734/wd/hub/session/6a989c27-04bf-45bd-a862-c3e340fe5023/timeouts

Comment: yes! /status return ->  player@devdevicelabs-Mac-mini Scripts % curl -X GET http://0.0.0.0:8734/wd/hub/status
{"value":{"build":{"version":"1.20.2"}},"sessionId":null,"status":0}